# Firebase: First date > open is greater than

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics

I tried to create audience: users who open app later than 25.07.2016. (screenshot). 
Does comparison works for dates?

[image]

Comment: Once you define your audience, users will be added to that audience from that moment forward. Users are not added to an audience retroactively. If that doesn't help: can you describe what problem are you having?

Comment: My problem is that I am not sure that I can use a comparison like "> greather than" for dates. Is it possible? Or comparison is only for numbers?

Comment: Good question. Let's see if someone more knowledgeable on Firebase Analytics appears. :-)

Comment: Maybe... Do you know someone who can help?

Comment: I just added a condition on an audience for `First Open Time > 7/28/2016`. Since the UI allows it, I expect users will show up in this audience over time. Don't they show up for you after you added a relative date condition?